# Upgrading Sublime-Text using snap - no updates available but new version is available

Tags: sublime-text-3, snap

My Sublime Text 4 just informed me that an update was available. Since I installed it using snap I wanted to update it using snap but snap tells me that no ST updates are available. My current build is 4121 and the latest build is 4126.

```
snap refresh sublime-text       
snap "sublime-text" has no updates available
```

Is there a way to update ST using snap?

Answer (score 0):

As with all package managers, there's a dependency on the publishing party to release to the correct channels. Evidently, in this case, the Sublime text team haven't updated the version number in the `latest/stable` channel.

You may need to contact the Sublime team to remind them to update the version number(s) in their channels.

Comment: can you tell me more about the channels? What are they and where are they?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)